# How to add a subdomain on GoDaddy on Azure site

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain

Lest say I have a web application called example.com

everything is ok with it and both www.example.com and example.com redirect to the correct A record "@" defined on the GoDaddy Zone file.

The thing is, that my back office web application is on a different Azure server than the main site (site is on example.com and the back office needs to be on office.example.com).
for that i have created another server on Azure.
example.com is on example.azurewebsites.net
office.example.com is on example-office.azurewebsites.net
(azure management site shows that both server have the same ip)

(Btw, is that what I should have done?)

What I tried was:
 1. add "office" A Record on Goddady that redirects the same ip (in addition to @) - didnt work.
 2. add "office" CNAME that redirects to example-office.azurewebsites.net - didnt work

In both cases i added the awverify and the awverify.www as followed:

awverify.office is awverify.example-office.azurewebsites.com
awverify.www.office is awverify.www.example-office.azurewebsites.com

Azure Manage Domains doesnt recognize office.example.com

What should I do at GoDaddy's to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: You're on the right track. You need to first add the CNAME record office to point to example-office.azurewebsites.com, then add the domain office.example.com to the azure website (this will check for the CNAME record before it accepts, remember that it could take up to an hour or more for this to catch your new DNS zone updates).

Answer (score 2):

you can find solution (godaddy screenshots included) here
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-godaddy-custom-domain-name/

- CNAME or A records pointing to IP or domain is right solution
- adding awverify is needed only if using A record
- better solution is to use CNAME - after stopping web service and starting again, you will receive probably different IP addres in azure (or you can use traffic manager)